# pip install django timeout on MacOSX Lion

Tags: python, django, osx-lion, pip

On a MBP, following instructions (http://techblog.rosedu.org/python-environment.html), I installed Xcode 4.4.1, brew (brew doctor says all set), and then python. Next, I tried to setup virtualenv:

```
> $MYPYTHON/bin/python distribute_setup.py
> $MYPYTHON/bin/easy_install pip
> $MYPYTHON/bin/pip install virtualenv
```

I then created a virtual environment and tried to install django:

```
> $MYPYTHON/bin/virtualenv $MYENV
> $MYENV/bin/pip install Django
```

It downloads 98% and then hangs for a while, and finally I get a traceback indicating a timeout:

```
pcm@pcm-mac[302]% $MYENV/bin/pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.4.1.tar.gz (7.7Mb): 7.5Mb downloaded
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pcm/Documents/workspace/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/pcm/Documents/workspace/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 245, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Users/pcm/Documents/workspace/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 985, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "/Users/pcm/Documents/workspace/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1109, in unpack_url
    retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir)
  File "/Users/pcm/Documents/workspace/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 451, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/Users/pcm/Documents/workspace/virtual/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 368, in _download_url
    chunk = resp.read(4096)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 553, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
timeout: timed out
```

I see the same thing, if I just run the version of pip from /usr/local/bin/.  I tried other packages (selenium, mock) and they downloaded and installed fine.

I'm at a loss as to what I may be doing wrong, or if there is some issue with django installs via pip. Advice?

Comment: The same is happening to me. It might be just a server-not-available issue. Try again in a few hours.

Comment: Try running pip with `--mirrors` options enabled.

Comment: I retried this morning, before trying with --mirrors option, and it worked. Must have been a server issue, as mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @HugoTavares What is a URL to use with --mirrors

Comment: Having this same problem on an Ubuntu machine but I'll never know how to fix it now since this question was closed as "unlikely to help any future visitors"...

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
pip --default-timeout=60 install django
```