# "SSLError: The read operation timed out" when using pip

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I try to install something with `pip` I get the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking Django>=1.5.1,<1.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.5.4.tar.gz (8.1MB): 8.0MB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1092, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1238, in unpack_url
    retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir)
  File "/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 622, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 495, in _download_url
    chunk = resp.read(4096)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 561, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: The read operation timed out

Storing complete log in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log
```

This used to happen to me from time to time, but now I can't install anything. I tried adding `--timeout=600`, but it fails in the same amount of time (a few seconds after reaching 8.0M).
Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using your own PyPI mirror or any kind of proxy server?

Comment: Nope. Using pip out-of-the-box with the regular server.

Comment: This is happening on just one computer? If yes, why not try to figure out which URL it's trying to fetch, and seeing if `curl -O`/`wget` on it work out fine.

Comment: `easy_install --dry-run 'Django>=1.5.1,<1.6'` told me that the URL is `https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.4.tar.gz#md5=b2685469bb4d1fbb091316e21f4108de`

Comment: `curl -O` on the url you pasted works fine and I get the same md5 sum as well.

Comment: Python 2.7.5's ssl module has a security fix that sometimes causes problems with transparent proxies and IIS. I can't recall the issue number out of my head, though.

Answer (score 36):

try (note the --default):

```
pip --default-timeout=100 install django
```

if it still doesn't work, you can manually download [django1.5.4](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.5.4/tarball/) and:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-manually

**similar questions:**

[pip search django produces time out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847470/pip-search-django-produces-time-out-error) ,
[pip install django timeout on MacOSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147519/pip-install-django-timeout-on-macosx-lion)

Answer (score 15):

That usually happens because of weak internet connection i.e; loss of internet connection during installation redo the command and it should work fine.

Comment: 1+ true, i also having same problem and my network too slow.