# Having trouble installing Django from Windows cmd. "pip install django" showing error although PATH should be set

Tags: python, django, windows

My macbook got stolen so now I'm trying re-install Django using Windows (7) cmd.
I did some research here in StackOverflow and couldn't find an answer that's working.

Used this question as a reference and set PATH using `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"`: ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-installing-django-w)

I'm now in C:\Python34 in the cmd and it's resulting in same "not recognized as an internal or external command" error.

When I try: `C:\Python34\Scripts> pip install django` it results in an 'Exception" error: `Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\myname\pip\pip.log`

I'm not sure what's going and I was wondering if there was a simpler way to approach the issue, since I'm very new to programming.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
Downloading/unpacking django
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  URLs to search for versions for django:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=07f0d2d42162945d0ad031fc9737847d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.5.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=1e3418bd1d6f9725a3d1264c9352f2a1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=c7b7a4437b36400f1c23953e9700fd29 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3bd014923e85df771b34d12c0ab3c9e1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=2bcdb4729f9f358b0925b532eef0a8ff (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.5.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=c35cb78bbf20a8ef60d37207d75a0f34 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.12
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=1078059a13d83a091e952917d22da9af (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=f83dcaec9e3b7d956a4d29e9401b0b97 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.10
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=e5937a962ce1298ac67d1aa7484883a6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=8093262e13535869720d7100aed72fd6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=74ffe011439efffcefbda6fac294c6f6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=72a2df8d67a976208420eec2fe2129fe (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=1cb695150210433200929623f800edcb (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.6.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=279bc0f844c644939dbe2a77c2249124 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=15efe093b40d058acf24682c31e7b24c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=83bd3e5cfba6d6d2bee5a37efb34771c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=b57f9a2dec214b60e338aa80fb902936 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=bd24beec81e161d30ad925aef9d23e57 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=f465b25daeaa559ffc329f1e5daaa520 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.8a1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=f7619792a8d8028c5be10f7d06a444ca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.8a1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.1.3.tar.gz#md5=52848c23dbc120fe0b2a8e7189b20306 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.1.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.1.4.tar.gz#md5=e818668acc4de944f85e494ac80f1e7d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.1.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.1.tar.gz#md5=2351efb20f6b7b5d9ce80fa4cb1bd9ca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.2.tar.gz#md5=9cdbf79a31988ace9ef2ab4ede890136 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.3.tar.gz#md5=10bfb5831bcb4d3b1e6298d0e41d6603 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.4.tar.gz#md5=b0e67d3d6447f7eb1ce6392b9465a183 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.5.tar.gz#md5=e031ea3d00996035e49e4bfa86e07c40 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.6.tar.gz#md5=bff9fc7d871c0b5e6ce1a7babd16847b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.7.tar.gz#md5=902fe294a2f7b16e5e1dee42d458c2ba (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.2.tar.gz#md5=98fa833fdabcdd78d00245aead66c174 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.1.tar.gz#md5=62d8642fd06b9a0bf8544178f8500767 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.2.tar.gz#md5=b8409b8f061e6c7a7dcfbb24403cb863 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.3.tar.gz#md5=cbdd86f553b26459352e26ae643fd7c1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.4.tar.gz#md5=9a610a40ee5fcc4ca283fb499e265936 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.5.tar.gz#md5=ec0ae9edb2ed6f9ffa65007110232637 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.6.tar.gz#md5=357dbedf41ba6db990fd4be7c86cd80d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.7.tar.gz#md5=f6720daa392d73d4df8847b41909fd43 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.3.tar.gz#md5=1b8f76e91c27564708649671f329551f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=e345268dacff12876ae4e45de0a61b7d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.10.tar.gz#md5=d324aecc37ce5430f548653b8b1509b6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.10
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.11.tar.gz#md5=9cd5913b038ebc9582903b2fccbbb54b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.11
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.12.tar.gz#md5=9dc17c3f5409f9a4e662b5550e1c6505 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.12
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.13.tar.gz#md5=9e28e33680f28b027ad67a026a785ea5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.13
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.14.tar.gz#md5=80dc1b9866487afc2ab3f774e29181bc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.14
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.15.tar.gz#md5=84837da82df11d0e04b7458af8777dc0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.15
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.16.tar.gz#md5=132d088d9e2cbcf43a661a9f05d6e63a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.16
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.17.tar.gz#md5=8dd1133b718ce23a0eed3df20d6619c2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.17
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.18.tar.gz#md5=d82b2219052bb47ba0838c2ebd3832ae (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.18
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.19.tar.gz#md5=8ebda674e81c3886a67eecc72e3f62df (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.19
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.2.tar.gz#md5=6ffecdc01ad360e1abdca1015ae0893a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.3.tar.gz#md5=0b134c44b6dc8eb36822677ef506c9ab (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.4.tar.gz#md5=833f531479948201f0f0a3b5b5972565 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.5.tar.gz#md5=851d00905eb70e4aa6384b3b8b111fb7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.6.tar.gz#md5=5c222ba388f8729151f2fda6be20af90 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.7.tar.gz#md5=28da2e8111ff951adbfce0651f945326 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.8.tar.gz#md5=7075e08ef06155e07002189b837cde85 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.9.tar.gz#md5=cc0c9752b46de362bd2114a65871330f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.4.tar.gz#md5=ba8e86198a93c196015df0b363ab1109 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=7465f6383264ba167a9a031d6b058bff (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.10.tar.gz#md5=b055361f04c0b8e862f8e8ffbb44e464 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.10
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.11.tar.gz#md5=6e88cab476e5149812accc143d313a22 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.11
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.12.tar.gz#md5=0e0b48cd0bb59cbc5499dcbb4fe1fb90 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.12
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=26e83e6394a15a86212777d5f61eae86 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.3.tar.gz#md5=1581e28b4aeb269c34a9b0417e103aaa (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.4.tar.gz#md5=b2685469bb4d1fbb091316e21f4108de (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.5.tar.gz#md5=e33355ee4bb2cbb4ab3954d3dff5eddd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.6.tar.gz#md5=b46fe29c7d26310d19aec6d8666f08c6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.7.tar.gz#md5=a2c127e85a34c2eb6c74db4f7e02d4e4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.8.tar.gz#md5=675fc736e2c29090f005e217ccf90b5b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.9.tar.gz#md5=4c6f03748043a32059d905033e0dc770 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.tar.gz#md5=fac09e1e0f11bb83bb187d652a9be967 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.1.tar.gz#md5=3ea7a00ea9e7a014e8a4067dd6466a1b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.10.tar.gz#md5=d7123f14ac19ae001be02ed841937b91 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.10
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.2.tar.gz#md5=45d974c623b3bfbf9976f3d808fe1ee9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.3.tar.gz#md5=727fec03f15db8f80a7231696b79adf7 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.4.tar.gz#md5=0d23bf836d3a52d93aee9411eccaa609 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.5.tar.gz#md5=e4c5b2d35ecb3807317713afa70a0c77 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.6.tar.gz#md5=d14fd332f31799fff39acc0c79e8421c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.7.tar.gz#md5=f31e2f953feb258e3569e962790630b6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.8.tar.gz#md5=b00f9f73535db7c9ce52a6f707d61ab6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.8
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.9.tar.gz#md5=03893cd1232f6cf75f0523e1b2c91ed2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.9
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.6.tar.gz#md5=65db1bc313124c3754c89073942e38a8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.7.1.tar.gz#md5=81dae89f21647b9aa5c46c6b7dbfa349 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.7.2.tar.gz#md5=855a53a9a5581c62b6031c9b3bd80ec5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.7.3.tar.gz#md5=ea9a3fe7eca2280b233938a98c4a35a0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.7.4.tar.gz#md5=f8db10520f0268747d402a47a1a4b191 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.7.tar.gz#md5=03edab6828119aa9b32b2252d25eb38d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.7
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.8a1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=f7619792a8d8028c5be10f7d06a444ca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version 1.8a1 is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
  Using version 1.7.4 (newest of versions: 1.7.4, 1.7.4, 1.7.3, 1.7.3, 1.7.2, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.1, 1.7, 1.7, 1.6.10, 1.6.10, 1.6.9, 1.6.9, 1.6.8, 1.6.8, 1.6.7, 1.6.7, 1.6.6, 1.6.6, 1.6.5, 1.6.5, 1.6.4, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.1, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5.12, 1.5.12, 1.5.11, 1.5.10, 1.5.9, 1.5.8, 1.5.8, 1.5.7, 1.5.6, 1.5.5, 1.5.4, 1.5.3, 1.5.2, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5, 1.4.19, 1.4.18, 1.4.17, 1.4.16, 1.4.15, 1.4.14, 1.4.13, 1.4.12, 1.4.11, 1.4.10, 1.4.9, 1.4.8, 1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3, 1.2.7, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2, 1.1.4, 1.1.3)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=f465b25daeaa559ffc329f1e5daaa520 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/)
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir C:\Users\pradhans\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_pradhans...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 433, in _download_url
    for chunk in resp_read(4096):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 421, in resp_read
    chunk_size, decode_content=False):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 240, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 187, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 500, in read
    return super(HTTPResponse, self).read(amt)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 539, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 371, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 746, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 618, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

Comment: if you open the file C:\Users\myname\pip\pip.log in notepad what does it say?

Comment: @darwindave It's incredibly long, so I put it in an edit

Comment: perhaps you are having internet connectivity problems with pypi see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958508/sslerror-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-using-pip

Answer (score 2):

Best way to install python is to install a virtual environment per project. That way you will no longer have path issues.

```
C:\Python34-64\Scripts\pip3.4.exe install virtualenv -U
C:\Python34-64\Scripts\virtualenv-3.4.exe venv-test
.\venv-test\Scripts\activate
pip3.4.exe install setuptools -U
```

Note I have installed the 64 bit version of Python34 and the default directory is C:\Python34\

Comment: based on your edit, the path is not your issue, though it is something that may save issues. The other thing tricky with windows is when you need to compile dependencies. When you start to pip install xxxx and get Error messages about needing an compiler see http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/

Comment: Thanks @darwindave, that seemed to have worked. I'm not sure what the problem was in the first place, but I'll look into internet connectivity and the link you posted.

Comment: With 3.3+ you also have the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)  module, e.g. `py -3 -m venv venv-test`.

Answer (score 0):

Use and elevated Cmd Prompt and then `py -3.4 -m ensurepip -U --default-pip` to instal pip.
   After that use `py -3.4 -m pip install Django==1.8.3`