# Tensorflow instalation with anaconda3 python 3.5 got 'Read timed out error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm trying to install tensorflow-gpu
using python3.6 and anaconda 3
I'm following the instalation steps in the following link https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

1- I have Createed a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:

**C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6**

2- then Activated the conda environment by issuing the following command:

**C:> activate tensorflow**
(tensorflow)C:>

***but comming for the final step***  to install TensorFlow inside my conda environment. using that command  **pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu**
I got that error

```
(C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3) C:\WINDOWS\system32>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (67.6MB)
    25% |████████                        | 16.9MB 5.3kB/s eta 2:38:22Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 384, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 60, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 436, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 401, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Chaymae\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 307, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Well after that I have tried to install the cpu version I got the same error.
If anyone could help I would be thankful, I really want to start learning tensorflow.

Comment: It seems to be a network connection error. Does the error occur in exactly the same place (at 5%) when you try again?

Comment: No not the same place

Comment: Then you can try to download again and hope that the connection doesn't abort. If it fails every time, you can download it manually. But for that you have to know the URL. You may also need a tool that can handle unstable Internet connection and automatically resumes downloading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SSLError: The read operation timed out" when using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958508/sslerror-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-using-pip)

Comment: @user502144 tool that can handle unstable Internet connection from the comand Prompt?

Comment: Not necessarily from the command prompt. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36717/download-manager-that-automatically-continues-failed-downloads/36732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was only the problem of unstable Internet connection, it's installed now and running very well

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with timeout.

Did `pip --default-timeout=300 install tensorflow` but still having the same problem.

Search the web for more info and I manage to install TF using `pip`.

This was what I did to overcome the issue:

Run this line first

1. `conda config --set ssl_verify no`

Follow by this(you can change the timeout or just try it without the timeout)

2. `pip --default-timeout=300 install tensorflow`

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a problem of unstable internet connection. 
you can set the default-timeout to say 60 (sec). e.g. pip --default-timeout=60 install tensorflow