# "Read timed out" when installing TensorFlow with Chaquopy

Tags: python, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit, chaquopy

I am building an android app with python integrated into it. I used chaquopy to integrate python with android. I have installed TensorFlow 2.2 for it with python version 3.6.6. It installs all other python libraries, but after seeing the logs it reports this error while installing TensorFlow 2.1.0.

***Process 'command 'C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1***

The complete log of the build is attached. Please help me out resolving this error.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project E:\fyp_screens
>Configure project :app 
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractPythonBuildPackages UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:generateDebugPythonRequirements
Chaquopy: Installing for arm64-v8a
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0
Collecting six
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nltk
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/tensorflow/tensorflow-2.1.0-9-cp38-cp38-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting tqdm (from nltk)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/76/4697ce203a3d42b2ead61127b35e5fcc26bba9a35c03b32a2bd342a4c869/tqdm-4.46.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click (from nltk)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/3d/fa76db83bf75c4f8d338c2fd15c8d33fdd7ad23a9b5e57eb6c5de26b430e/click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting joblib (from nltk)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/a6/d1a816b89aa1e9e96bcb298eb1ee1854f21662ebc6d55ffa3d7b3b50122b/joblib-0.15.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting regex (from nltk)
  Using version 2020.1.8 (newest version is 2020.6.8, but Chaquopy prefers native wheels)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/regex/regex-2020.1.8-0-cp38-cp38-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/41/bbf49b61370e4f4d245d4c6051dfb6db80cec672605c91b1652ac8cc3d38/tensorboard-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.8 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gast==0.2.2 (from tensorflow)
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using version 1.17.4 (newest version is 1.18.5, but Chaquopy prefers native wheels)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/numpy/numpy-1.17.4-3-cp38-cp38-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/4c/7c3275a01e12ef9368a892926ab932b33bb13d55794881e3573482b378a7/Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3" (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/23/848298cccf8e40f5bbb59009b32848a4c38f4e7f3364297ab3c3e2e2cd14/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using version 1.26.0 (newest version is 1.29.0, but Chaquopy prefers native wheels)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/grpcio/grpcio-1.26.0-1-cp38-cp38-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/88/97eef84f48fa04fbd6750e62dcceafba6c63c81b7ac1420856c8dcc0a3f9/astor-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/de/c648ef6835192e6e2cc03f40b19eeda4382c49b5bafb43d88b931c4c74ac/google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/a5/e6c07b08b934831ccb8c98ee335e66b7761c5754ee3cabfe4c11d0b1af28/opt_einsum-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.2.0,>=2.1.0rc0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/90/b77c328a1304437ab1310b463e533fa7689f4bfc41549593056d812fab8e/tensorflow_estimator-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wrapt>=1.11.1 (from tensorflow)
Collecting protobuf>=3.8.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/90/27eac528bb6871336e86ed8bcbb72a9b412a4020bf69bb7be71d40e5eab0/protobuf-3.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chaquopy-libcxx>=7000 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-libcxx/chaquopy_libcxx-7000-2-py3-none-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting absl-py>=0.7.0 (from tensorflow)
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)
Collecting setuptools>=41.0.0 (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/95/f657b6e17f00c3f35b5f68b10e46c3a43af353d8856bd57bfcfb1dbb3e92/setuptools-47.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/63/eaec2bd025ab48c754b55e8819af0f6a69e2b1e187611dd40cbbe101ee7f/Markdown-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15 (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/94/5f7079a0e00bd6863ef8f1da638721e9da21e5bacee597595b318f71d62e/Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/b8/88def36e74bee9fce511c9519571f4e485e890093ab7442284f4ffaef60b/google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests<3,>=2.21.0 (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/70/1935c770cb3be6e3a8b78ced23d7e0f3b187f5cbfab4749523ed65d7c9b1/requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 (from tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/0e/a67880c055a835eee920ab0aba6a968ec954941c923ab36186586ac56896/google_auth-1.16.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting h5py (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/h5py/h5py-2.10.0-1-cp38-cp38-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting chaquopy-openblas>=0.2.20 (from numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-openblas/chaquopy_openblas-0.2.20-5-py3-none-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/12/b92740d845ab62ea4edf04d2f4164d82532b5a0b03836d4d4e71c6f3d379/requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e3/afebe61c546d18fb1709a61bee788254b40e736cff7271c7de5de2dc4128/idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/99/def511020aa8f663d4a2cfaa38467539e864799289ff354569e339e375b1/certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/e5/df302e8017440f111c11cc41a6b432838672f5a70aa29227bf58149dc72f/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/59/524ffb454d05001e2be74c14745b485681c6ed5f2e625f71d135704c0909/cachetools-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4 (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/e5/38518af393f7c214357079ce67a317307936896e961e35450b70fad2a9cf/rsa-4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/de/214830a981892a3e286c3794f41ae67a4495df1108c3da8a9f62159b9a9d/pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chaquopy-hdf5>=1.10.2 (from h5py->keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-hdf5/chaquopy_hdf5-1.10.2-1-py3-none-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting chaquopy-libgfortran>=4.9 (from chaquopy-openblas>=0.2.20->numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-libgfortran/chaquopy_libgfortran-4.9-0-py3-none-android_21_arm64_v8a.whl
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/ce2e7a8fa7c0afb54a0581b14a65b56e62b5759dbc98e80627142b8a3704/oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3 (from rsa<4.1,>=3.1.4->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.2.0,>=2.1.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/1e/a94a8d635fa3ce4cfc7f506003548d0a2447ae76fd5ca53932970fe3053f/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, tqdm, click, joblib, regex, nltk, absl-py, setuptools, chaquopy-libcxx, grpcio, markdown, werkzeug, cachetools, pyasn1, rsa, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, oauthlib, idna, chardet, certifi, urllib3, requests, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, wheel, chaquopy-libgfortran, chaquopy-openblas, numpy, protobuf, tensorboard, chaquopy-hdf5, h5py, keras-applications, gast, keras-preprocessing, astor, google-pasta, opt-einsum, tensorflow-estimator, wrapt, termcolor, tensorflow
Successfully installed absl-py-0.9.0 astor-0.8.1 cachetools-4.1.0 certifi-2020.4.5.2 chaquopy-hdf5-1.10.2 chaquopy-libcxx-7000 chaquopy-libgfortran-4.9 chaquopy-openblas-0.2.20 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 gast-0.2.2 google-auth-1.16.1 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.26.0 h5py-2.10.0 idna-2.9 joblib-0.15.1 keras-applications-1.0.8 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 markdown-3.2.2 nltk-3.5 numpy-1.17.4 oauthlib-3.1.0 opt-einsum-3.2.1 protobuf-3.12.2 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 regex-2020.1.8 requests-2.23.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.0 setuptools-47.1.1 six-1.15.0 tensorboard-2.1.1 tensorflow-2.1.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.1.0 termcolor-1.1.0 tqdm-4.46.1 urllib3-1.25.9 werkzeug-1.0.1 wheel-0.34.2 wrapt-1.12.1
Chaquopy: Installing for armeabi-v7a
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0
Collecting chaquopy-hdf5==1.10.2
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-hdf5/chaquopy_hdf5-1.10.2-1-py3-none-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl
Collecting chaquopy-libcxx==7000
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-libcxx/chaquopy_libcxx-7000-2-py3-none-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl
Collecting chaquopy-libgfortran==4.9
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-libgfortran/chaquopy_libgfortran-4.9-0-py3-none-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl
Collecting chaquopy-openblas==0.2.20
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/chaquopy-openblas/chaquopy_openblas-0.2.20-5-py3-none-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl
Collecting grpcio==1.26.0
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/grpcio/grpcio-1.26.0-1-cp38-cp38-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl
Collecting h5py==2.10.0
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/h5py/h5py-2.10.0-1-cp38-cp38-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl
Collecting numpy==1.17.4
  Downloading https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/numpy/numpy-1.17.4-3-cp38-cp38-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl (3.6MB)
Collecting regex==2020.1.8
  Using cached https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/regex/regex-2020.1.8-0-cp38-cp38-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl
Collecting tensorflow==2.1.0
  Downloading https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/tensorflow/tensorflow-2.1.0-9-cp38-cp38-android_16_armeabi_v7a.whl (61.5MB)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 384, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 60, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 236, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 310, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 312, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\download.py", line 841, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\download.py", line 678, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\download.py", line 902, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\download.py", line 624, in _download_url
    consume(downloaded_chunks)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 847, in consume
    deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\download.py", line 590, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 159, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_internal\download.py", line 579, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 436, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 401, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "E:\fyp_screens\app\build\generated\python\bp.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 307, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chaquo.com', port=443): Read timed out.
Chaquopy: Exit status 2

> Task :app:generateDebugPythonRequirements FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugPythonRequirements'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Armani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
  
  To view full details in Android Studio:
  * In version 3.6 and newer, click the 'Build: failed' caption to the left of this message.
  * In version 3.5 and older, click the 'Toggle view' button to the left of this message.
  * Then scroll up to see the full output.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7m 5s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Comment: How many times has this happened? Does it fail in the same way every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search results for this error indicate it's most likely caused by a slow or unstable internet connection. Try increasing the network timeout like this:

```
python {
    pip {
        options "--timeout", "1000"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens when you try to download the tensorflow library.

I found two links that might be interesting for you:

- ["SSLError: The read operation timed out" when using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958508/sslerror-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-using-pip)
- [Tensorflow instalation with anaconda3 python 3.5 got 'Read timed out error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610308/tensorflow-instalation-with-anaconda3-python-3-5-got-read-timed-out-error)