# Whenever tried installing python modules it shows the following error - how to resolve?

Tags: python

While installing a python package (matplotlib), I am getting this below error which basically advices to update the pip version:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/ea/68c35d642a7c8ca74f4053963743824802875bb6c0215e78aee17d0a16cc/matplotlib-3.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (9.2MB)
     |█████████                       | 2.7MB 14kB/s eta 0:07:26ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 397, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 479, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 305, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 195, in prepare_linked_requirement
    unpack_url(
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 1058, in unpack_url
    unpack_http_url(
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 920, in unpack_http_url
    from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(link,
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 1152, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 861, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\hashes.py", line 75, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 829, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 156, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 794, in resp_read
    for chunk in resp.raw.stream(
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 531, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 496, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\mageshkumar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 402, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Tried updating the pip as suggested by the previous error, but getting the exact same error: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Please any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can try the solution here!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958508/sslerror-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-using-pip

Comment: Mahesh, please see if this is helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port][1]