# TensorFlow Installation Problem On Windows 10 (Version 2.1.0 of Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I got this error while installing TensorFlow version 2.1.0 on Windows 10, I was installing the Tensorflow only, not the GPU one here help me solve and plz tell me why it occurs.

I open cmd and write `pip install -q tensorflow==2.1.0` and got this error and I want to know how to solve it.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.592]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Navin>pip install -q tensorflow==2.1.0
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 397, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 479, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 457, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 501, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 307, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 199, in prepare_linked_requirement
    progress_bar=self.progress_bar
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 1064, in unpack_url
    progress_bar=progress_bar
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 924, in unpack_http_url
    progress_bar)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 1152, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 861, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\hashes.py", line 75, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 829, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 818, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 531, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 496, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Navin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 402, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.

C:\Users\Navin>
```

Comment: Well, most probably you have an internet connection issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958508/sslerror-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-using-pip

Comment: The internet connection was ok, In error message, I got that occurs ``` During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:```

Comment: Yes, but both exceptions have to do with time outs - `socket.timeout: The read operation timed out` and `Read timed out`. I checked and `pip install` works for me OK. There might be something temporarily wrong with the servers, keep trying (see also the linked thread).

Comment: Should I try it to install in a virtual environment?

Comment: Doesn't seem the reason that it fails now. As said, keep trying - the linked thread says that a "weak internet connection" may be responsible for such behavior