# Pip install is not working to download yolov5

Tags: python, pip

when I am trying to install yolov5 to train custom data set it is showing so please help me some one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJmRA.png)

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958508/sslerror-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-using-pip and see if answers from there help?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the text to the question, rather than a print screen? it will make it easier for others to diagnose/help you. 

It seems like you have a problem installing opencv 4.5.5.64, can you try to install that by itself?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are showing has nothing to do with Yolov5, it is timeout error, most probably due to your slow internet speed 65kbps.

You can install it via git if your pip is not working.

You clone it from git.

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5  # clone
$ cd yolov5
$ pip install -r requirements.txt  # install
```

Now you can use pytorch hub to load the model

```py
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('path/to/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
```

Or even without cloning, directly use from pytorch hub.

Just install requirements first

```sh
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ultralytics/yolov5/master/requirements.txt
```

And then use directly via torch hub

```py
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s') # no local clone req
```

Comment: BTW your error does not seems to do anything with yolov5. It seems like a slow internet speed as it is 62kb/s so it times out.