# docker executor failed running

Tags: python, docker

I wrote a python script now I want to dockerize the script so I make a 'Dockerfile' and then I wrote `docker build -t price_updater_service.py .` but in final step after copying my 'requirements.txt' i got this error 'executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 2'.
atually problem is that image can't download package listed in my'requirements.txt'.
what else I can to do? is this any other way? also I'll put my 'requirements.txt' and my 'Dockerfile' here:

'requirements.txt'

```
pandas == 2.0
redis
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Python base image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python requirements file to the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install the Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the Python code to the container
COPY main.py .

# Run the Python script when the container starts
CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

full error trace:

```
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                                                                          169.8s 
------
 > [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:
#6 11.00 Collecting pandas==2.0
#6 12.16   Downloading pandas-2.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.4 MB)
#6 164.0      ━━━━                                     1.3/12.4 MB 4.3 kB/s eta 0:42:42
#6 164.0 ERROR: Exception:
#6 164.0 Traceback (most recent call last):
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
#6 164.0     yield
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 561, in read
#6 164.0     data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
#6 164.0     return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 463, in read
#6 164.0     n = self.readinto(b)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 507, in readinto
#6 164.0     n = self.fp.readinto(b)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
#6 164.0     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1242, in recv_into
#6 164.0     return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1100, in read
#6 164.0     return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
#6 164.0 socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
#6 164.0
#6 164.0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
#6 164.0
#6 164.0 Traceback (most recent call last):
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
#6 164.0     status = run_func(*args)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
#6 164.0     return func(self, options, args)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 419, in run
#6 164.0     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
#6 164.0     result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
#6 164.0     state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
#6 164.0     self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
#6 164.0     if not criterion.candidates:
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
#6 164.0     return bool(self._sequence)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
#6 164.0     return any(self)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
#6 164.0     return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
#6 164.0     candidate = func()
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
#6 164.0     self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
#6 164.0     super().__init__(
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
#6 164.0     self.dist = self._prepare()
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
#6 164.0     dist = self._prepare_distribution()
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
#6 164.0     return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
#6 164.0     return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 536, in _prepare_linked_requirement
#6 164.0     local_file = unpack_url(
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 166, in unpack_url
#6 164.0     file = get_http_url(
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 107, in get_http_url
#6 164.0     from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 147, in __call__
#6 164.0     for chunk in chunks:
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 53, in _rich_progress_bar
#6 164.0     for chunk in iterable:
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
#6 164.0     for chunk in response.raw.stream(
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 622, in stream
#6 164.0     data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 587, in read
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
#6 164.0     self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
#6 164.0   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
#6 164.0     raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
#6 164.0 pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
#6 169.6
#6 169.6 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.2
#6 169.6 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 2
PS C:\Users\hesam\OneDrive\Desktop\sam\python_django_test\price_update> docker build -t price_updater_service.py .
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                          0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                           0.0s 
[+] Building 103.0s (8/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                          0.2s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                           0.1s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                             0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim                                                                                            3.8s 
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim@sha256:5f0192a4f58a6ce99f732fe05e3b3d00f12ae62e183886bca3ebe3d202686c7f                                      0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 81B                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                                                                           99.0s 
------
 > [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:
#7 53.23 Collecting pandas==2.0
#7 55.65   Downloading pandas-2.0.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.4 MB)
#7 94.83                                               0.0/12.4 MB 2.5 kB/s eta 1:21:34
#7 94.84 ERROR: Exception:
#7 94.84 Traceback (most recent call last):
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
#7 94.84     yield
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 561, in read
#7 94.84     data = self._fp_read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 527, in _fp_read
#7 94.84     return self._fp.read(amt) if amt is not None else self._fp.read()
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 463, in read
#7 94.84     n = self.readinto(b)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 507, in readinto
#7 94.84     n = self.fp.readinto(b)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
#7 94.84     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1242, in recv_into
#7 94.84     return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1100, in read
#7 94.84     return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
#7 94.84 socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
#7 94.84
#7 94.84 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
#7 94.84
#7 94.84 Traceback (most recent call last):
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
#7 94.84     status = run_func(*args)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
#7 94.84     return func(self, options, args)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 419, in run
#7 94.84     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
#7 94.84     result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
#7 94.84     state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
#7 94.84     self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
#7 94.84     if not criterion.candidates:
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
#7 94.84     return bool(self._sequence)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
#7 94.84     return any(self)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
#7 94.84     return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
#7 94.84     candidate = func()
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
#7 94.84     self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 297, in __init__
#7 94.84     super().__init__(
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 162, in __init__
#7 94.84     self.dist = self._prepare()
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 231, in _prepare
#7 94.84     dist = self._prepare_distribution()
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 308, in _prepare_distribution
#7 94.84     return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 491, in prepare_linked_requirement
#7 94.84     return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 536, in _prepare_linked_requirement
#7 94.84     local_file = unpack_url(
#7 94.84   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line
```

Comment: Can you update your post with full error trace?

Comment: sure it's updated now.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958508/sslerror-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-using-pip -- your connection seems to be timing out when docker is installing pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is coz of conection intruption. i use VPN for docker and pip is not working well when you use VPN.